# Почему не скачивается PDF?

Tags: битрикс, debian

В папке лежит файл 1.pdf размером до 1 мб.
Нужно по ссылке его скачать.

```
https://site.com.ua/shzurnal/download/1.pdf
```

Однако при переходе по этой ссылке выбрасывает 404-ю страницу и добавляет в конце слеш.

Картинки нормально открывает из этой же папки.

Или что-то важное я забыл или какие-то настройки не позволяют.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: .htaccess из коробки?

Comment: Есть вот такие правила. Больше про jpeg ничего не нашел.

Comment: В какой папке лежит файл? В поддиректории `/download/` директории `/shzurnal/`? Как выглядит ссылка на файл в коде сайта?

Comment: Да нет. Вас перебрасывает на `virtual_file_system.php` или на `urlrewrite.php`. Из любой другой папки файл скачивается? Например положите в `bitrix` и попробуйте `https://site.com.ua/bitrix/1.pdf`

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry Да

Comment: @ Андрей ProjectSoft так работает, да.

Comment: @ Андрей ProjectSoft а как же сделать, чтоб из текущей открывался?

Comment: Да, вижу такие правила в .htaccess: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]

Comment: Закомментировал, но все-равно ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Добавил исключение RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/shzurnal/ все получилось